# Grails hasMany association check

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, has-many

What is the cheapest way (from performance stand point) to figure out if hasMany association has any members?  I am trying to avoid retrieval of all children. Is there a clean way to count children using gorm?

The use case here is to show(or not) a [+] on the UI of a parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible i guess with a straight gorm expression

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to lose anything (especially if utilizing caching) by doing a size() check on the children.  Another option would be to de-normalize a bit and keep a count as a column on the parent.  We do this for an ecomm site that tracks the number of order items for an order header.

You could also look into the countBy dynamic finder.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't like de-normalizing solution as you are introducing a maintenance task to keep counts in sync. Also you are introducing potential for errors when counts are not in sync.      The size check is causing all children to be retrieved that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Look into the countBy dynamic finder.  You could do a child.countByParent(parent).  That "should" generate a select count(*)" of some sort, which may offer you better performance.